# Low graphics mode after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I have an ATI Radeon 3200 graphics card.

I just upgraded to 12.04 and I get the `System running low graphics...` error code.

```
Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly.
```

It is exactly the same problem as one or two previous questions. So I tried their solutions to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install fglrx`

The only answer I get is  `You allready have the latest sw`.

And my problem with `System running low graphics...` is still there.
So what do I do? For the time being I run the previous version. It worked perfectly.
Gunnar

Answer (score 6):

I have recently experienced the same thing, I have **Intel** based graphics card.

I fixed  the following way:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go to a shell

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Choose **gdm** when prompted.

Then do a `shutdown -r now` and voila.

Let me know if it fixed for ya.

Comment: I picked lightdm, not gdm (Xubuntu) and also did this: http://askubuntu.com/a/195805/64529

Comment: You're my hero.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by switching from lightdm to gdm. Press Ctrl+alt+F2, then login as root, then issue the following commands.

apt-get install gdm
dpkg-reconfigure gdm

And choose gdm.

I thought it was a driver issue, but I'm able to use unity 2d now, with gdm, and with open source drivers. I reported a bug about it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/993579

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I tried it but the I got the answer " can't find dpkg-reconfigure" Have you got any idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

I found the fault myself. Somehow I had both the generic-pae kernel an the generic kernel. It seems as if my laptop cant handle the the -pae one. When I switched over to the generic one it works fine. Unfortunately the appeared as the default while the generic appeared in the previous version sektor. I used a tool "Grub Customizer" to get the generic one as the default.
I tried to install 12.04 directly from a disk as well and when I did that I got the correct kernel as the default. I do not understand why it ended up wrong when I upgrade but correct when installed from the disk.
Anyhow it works perfect now
cheers Gunnar

Comment: The fglrx driver is built with DKMS. You need the `linux-headers-<KERNEL VERSION>` packages installed for being able to use these DKMS packages. To install the package for the currently loaded kernel, use `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.