# How to fix Xubuntu LightDM Theme after installing unity.

Tags: themes, xubuntu, lightdm, css, etc

After successfully installing Xubuntu 12.04.1 on my laptop, I decided to install Unity. That went OK but then I realized there was no themes. So then I installed the themes and artwork, and got a really bad surprise. My lightDM greeter was still Xubuntu like I wanted but the buttons where you choose the user are really tall and I have a purple computer as the icon above my computer name. How do I get back to the original Xubuntu configuration or edit the CSS while keeping Unity? I know where all of the files are but don't know which file to edit or which CSS property to modify.

Packages Installed:

```
unity unity-services unity-mail
```

Then I Installed:

```
ubuntu-artwork light-themes ubuntu-wallpapers-oneric ubuntu-wallpapers-precise
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the content of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. To get back to the Xubuntu config, make sure the `greeter-session` parameter is set to 'lightdm-gtk-greeter', ...like this:

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

To edit the file, run `gksu leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Comment: No thats not it. It's properly set. Is there a CSS option.

Comment: There might be, but I don't know. :)

Comment: This fixed a different thing for me, it fixed the known "System running in low graphics mode", after switching from Unity to Xubuntu.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, Xubuntu uses the gtk-greater.

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco how do you fix "System running in low graphics mode"?

Comment: I did this: http://askubuntu.com/a/181744/64529 (but picked lightdm) and also did what mikewhatever said, on a Xubuntu desktop.