# Ubuntu boots to black screen after update

Tags: 12.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Updated to 12.10 from .04 and set the graphics to light, since it was the default option I assumed that was the one I had always been using.

So after the update the screen ends up in low graphics mode and I get a menu which I can't see, not wanting to make another uninformed decision, I google it, and find out that I just have to switch to gdm.

[Low graphics mode after upgrade to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128375/low-graphics-mode-after-upgrade-to-12-04)

The final step was to run shutdown -r, this didn't work, it said something about not supplying TIME. So I manually shut it down assuming that it would lead to the same outcome.

spoilers: it didn't

It just boots to a black screen, I'm guessing the gdm didn't install right. Anyway I can fix this or is that all she wrote?

Comment: if you check the man page of the `shutdown` command you will see that it needs a time argument after the option argument : `shutdown [OPTION]...  TIME [MESSAGE]` and you should use capital H `shutdown -H now` http://askubuntu.com/questions/190202/difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-now#comment235859_190214